# Displaying colons in Mediawiki URLs on IIS 7.5

Tags: url-rewriting, hyperlink, iis-7.5, mediawiki, urlencode

After pulling my hair out trying to get my local IIS server to not encode colons in MediaWiki links (turning `http://localhost/wiki/Category:People` into `http://localhost/wiki/Category$3APeople`) I'm beginning to think that such a feat is impossible. Of particular interest is that both links work when entered, it's just that all the links throughout the wiki display as the encoded version. Since both work, it's purely a visual annoyance, but one I would like to solve if possible.

As an alternative, I'm wondering if it is possible to merely change the display of the links. If MediaWiki/IIS is so insistent on encoding colons in URLs, fine, but is it possible to show the user the colon, regardless of what the actual link is?

I understand that colons in urls on windows servers are not allowed because they would open access to data file streams, but as this is a private wiki running on my local machine, I would not be opposed to disabling this security precaution if possible.

I originally posted this question on the MediaWiki Users Forum back in June, but have not received any help in solving the issue. That thread can be found at http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?18722-IIS-7.5-Percent-encoding-all-colons-in-URLs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escaping of colons by MediaWiki on IIS 7 is a [deliberate workaround](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22709) for [a bug in IIS 7.5](http://forums.iis.net/p/1165517/1936321.aspx) that causes URLs containing a combination of unescaped colons and non-ASCII characters to be mangled under certain circumstances.

The client side jQuery workaround described by eduncan911 should be fine, but the proper solution (given that the bug does not appear to have ever been fixed in IIS 7.5, as far as I can tell) would presumably be to upgrade to Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.0 (or to some other HTTP server that does not exhibit the bug).

Comment: +1 And thanks! I was just about to move to W2K12 for my VM, and seeing it is a work-around built into MW, I will have my making the move sooner than later.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Just to be cautious, I should note that I don't actually _know_ for sure that the bug's been fixed in IIS 8, but I'd certainly hope so. At least, the workaround in MediaWiki only applies to IIS 7, so if any other version of IIS needs it then that's also a bug in MediaWiki.

Comment: As soon as I get the opportunity to see if this is still an issue in IIS 8.0 (whether or not the original IIS bug still exists) I'll pick the answer, but thanks for shedding light on this. I looked around forever and could not find anything that suggested this was intentional.

Comment: Finally got around to updating my machine to Win 8.1 with IIS 8.5 and MediaWiki no longer has this issue.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My original answer is still below, but I was wrong in "assuming".  The problem is described in Ilmari's answer.  It is because IIS 7.0/7.5 has a Microsoft-confirmed bug in classifying urls with colons as malformed/hack attempts (it isn't).  He suggests upgrading to IIS 8.0 (Windows Server 2012) to resolve it, even though that hasn't been confirmed.

I am in the process of moving my machines over to Windows Server 2012, and will come back and update this answer once I can confirm that is working.

Original answer below.

--

As far I can see, it is PHP 5.4 running on Windows as with identical setups and config files, my RedHat machine doesn't do it whereas IIS does.  FastCGI may be a way around it as well.

I initially attempted to created an Outbound rule but kept having to create so many conditions to get around MediaWiki's special url requirements.

Therefore, I just ended up putting this jquery snippet in for now.

```
$('a').each( function() {
  this.href = this.href.replace(/%3A/g, ":");
});
```

When I get around to sitemap (this is a new install), I'll make sure they are parsed out of that as well.

Also note I ran into some security violation errors as well with the colons, because .NET ass-u-mes that a colon is a bad character.  To get around that, add this to your web.config file running in that directory:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" 
        requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,>,*,%,&amp;,\" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I definitely went down this route as well, making colons accepted and creating rewrite rules, but I could never quite get it working properly. Knowing MediaWiki did it intentionally is kinda annoying, since it looks like the real problem is that their "fix" isn't strict enough and catches cases that don't trigger the bug as well.